# SQL - Get the most recent data

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Hi guys I hope you can help me!

I have done this piece of code here:

```
" SELECT distinct left(ut.Text,27) " & _
" FROM [MyDataBase].[dbo].[table1] ut, dbo.table2 u " & _
" WHERE ut.table1 in (select unitid from dbo.table2 where serialno like '" & CStr(Right(Sheet1.Cells(i, 3), 8)) & "' ) " & _
" AND ut.text like 'EPP:%' " & _
" AND u.table2 = ut.table1 " & _
" ORDER BY 1 "
```

It works perfectly! What it does?
I have a sheet like this:

```
ORDER   PID         SERIAL
3033421 6625MC3209  13-49026969
3033421 6625MC3209  13-49027001
```

It gets the information on the third column and uses it to search and paste the data from the database into the fourth column.

My problem is: the query pastes the first information it gets and actually I need it to get the last information (or to be more precise the latest information added). To illustrate:

```
ORDER   PID         SERIAL         EPP
3033421 6625MC3209  13-49026969    123456789   2015-01-25
3033421 6625MC3209  13-49026969    987654321   2015-03-25
```

My query is pasting the data that dates 2015-01-25 and I need it to paste the data that dates 2015-03-25 (that is the most recent one).

Hope it is clear :P
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to do order by your date column DESC?

Comment: I am trying using it Alariva, but my concern is that this piece of code is just one module (it searches just EPP), I have two other modules that work very similar (they just search for a different data, HAM and MASH codes respectively) and they work together. Each data goes in one row of the following columns (EPP column 3, HAM column 4 and MASH column 5). I don't want the column "date" for instance to be shown in the sheet but I need that the  date in each row of each column is the latest data added in the database.